# Magento 2 : Tab Content

Tags: magento2, product, ajax, jquery, tabs

I am  trying to create tab on frontend with ajax call.

I created phtml file and put these code:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="navcontainer">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="tab1" href="tabs.php?id=1">google</a></li>
                <li><a id="tab2" href="tabs.php?id=2">yahoo</a></li>
                <li><a id="tab3" href="tabs.php?id=3">rediff</a></li>
                <li><a id="tab4" href="tabs.php?id=4">youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



        <div id="tabcontent">
            <?php
            $p = $_GET['id'];
            switch($p) { 
        case "1":
            echo '<h2>google</h2>Content goes here !<br style="clear:both;" />';
            break;
        case "2":
            echo 'yahoo ?<br style="clear:both;" />';
            break;
        case "3": 
            echo 'My rediff content goes here...<br style="clear:both;" />';
            break;
        case "4":
        default:
            echo 'youtube status update :)<br style="clear:both;" />';
            break;
            }
            ?>

        </div>
```

and js code used:

```
</style>
            <script type="text/javascript">         
        require(['jquery'],
        function loadTabContent(tabUrl){
            $("#preloader").show();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url:tabUrl , 
                cache: false,
                success: function(message) {
                    jQuery("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
                    $("#preloader").hide();
                }
            });
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){              

            $("#preloader").hide();             
            jQuery("[id^=tab]").click(function(){   

                // get tab id and tab url
                tabId = $(this).attr("id");                                     
                tabUrl = jQuery("#"+tabId).attr("href");

                jQuery("[id^=tab]").removeClass("current");
                jQuery("#"+tabId).addClass("current");

                // load tab content
                loadTabContent(tabUrl);
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
```

but its not worked, because in navcontainer,the href is wrong. if I put code in controller then how should I call it here to show in tab content?

Comment: Please refer:- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/ , may that help you

Comment: I am not creating tab for product  view page. its a custome tabs to different usase.